# Javascript: percentage difference between two values

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript code to display the difference in percentage between two values.

```
A = 11192;
B = 10474;

percDiff = (vars.A - vars.B) / vars.B * 100;
```

Which gives: 6.855069696391064

Then

```
if (percDiff > 20) {
  //dosomething
} else {
  //dosomething
}
```

**The problem is:**

If value B is higher than value A then i get a NaN, for instance;
[image: NaN]

How can I overcome this issue? I thought about using `Math.abs()`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are `vars.A` and `vars.B` equal to `A` and `B`? I didn't get 6.855 when I tried it. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cpX27/

Comment: How are you getting `NaN` there? `percDiff` is just a float...

Comment: Hmm, not sure why you'd get NaN as `( 10474 - 11192) / 10474 * 100` would give -6.855069696391064.

Comment: sorry its suppose to be divided by vars.B, ill update the code

Comment: Where do you get the numbers from? In case they are from an input field, use `parseInt()` to convert them to numbers first.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the `NaN` doesn't make sense. How are you setting the values to / getting them from those fields?

Comment: Yeah, make sure you're actually using integers, not strings

Comment: Okay, I am going to parseInt, brb

Comment: And i was just looking for something like this yesterday :/.

Comment: @Meredith—since the `+` operator isn't being used, it doesn't matter if the values are strings or numbers since the mathematic operations will convert them to numbers anyway.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think you can use this formula to determine the relative difference (percentage) between 2 values:

```
var percDiff =  100 * Math.abs( (A - B) / ( (A+B)/2 ) );
```

Here's a utility method:

```
function relDiff(a, b) {
 return  100 * Math.abs( ( a - b ) / ( (a+b)/2 ) );
}
// example
relDiff(11240, 11192); //=> 0.42796005706134094
```

**Note** for people thinking the answer provides a wrong result: this question/answer concerns percentage [***difference***](//www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-difference.html)<sup>1</sup>, **not** percentage [***change***](//www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/percentage-change.html)<sup>2</sup>.

Here's a snippet to demonstrate the difference (pun intended;)

```js
const relativePercentageDifference = (a, b) => 
  Math.abs( ( ( a - b ) / ( ( a + b ) / 2 ) ) * 100 );
const percentageChange = (a, b) => ( b / a * 100 ) - 100;
console.log(`relative % difference 2000 - 1000: ${
  relativePercentageDifference(2000, 1000).toFixed(2)}%`);
console.log(`% change 2000 - 1000: ${
  percentageChange(2000, 1000).toFixed(2)}%`);
console.log(`relative % difference 1000 - 2000: ${
  relativePercentageDifference(1000, 2000).toFixed(2)}%`);
console.log(`% change 1000 - 2000: ${
  percentageChange(1000, 2000).toFixed(2)}%`);
```

[**JsFiddle**](//kooi.dev/showFiddle/kgkJF)

<sup>1</sup> *The percentual difference between two values divided by the average of the two values.*

<sup>2</sup> *The percentual difference (in-/decrease) between two numbers divided by the original number.*

Comment: Apparently I get NaN because the result of the equation is 0.xxxxx and therefore is an unrepresentable value.

Comment: Added a utility method to the answer. If you still get `NaN`, (one of) the input value(s) is not numeric I suppose.

Comment: thanks for this, i also found out that there was an issue with the variable being case sensitive and that was the reason I was getting a NaN

Comment: Adding `+`  before a and b will remove NaN

Comment: this returns 66.7% for `2000` and `1000`, which is wrong imo...?

Comment: @devman It's the percentage _difference_. Read about it @ http://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-difference.html, esp. the part under '_Why do we Average the Two Values?_'

Comment: Answer seems to be wrong, downvoting. Returns 66.7 for this relDiff(100, 50) which is wrong. Correct answer would be https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/557/how-to-calculate-a-percentage-change-increase-and-decrease-from-2-values-in-javascript

Comment: @ozcanovunc *percentage difference*: the difference between two values divided by the average of the two values. Shown as a percentage. Please read the [aforementioned article](https://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-difference.html). Your link is about percentage *change*

Answer (score 1):

```
diffPercent = function(a, b) {
 return  ( a<b ? "-" + ((b - a) * 100) / a : ((a - b) * 100) / b ) + "%";
}
```

Comment: I don't think returning a string is going to be as useful as just returning the calculation. Also, why concatenate the "-"? Why not just negate?

Comment: the result is the either way around but it's a nice function

Answer (score 1):

in the case when we need to know the difference of some number to the etalon number:

```
function percDiff(etalon, example) {
  return  +Math.abs(100 - example / etalon * 100).toFixed(10);
}
// example
percDiff(11240, 11192); //=> 0.4270462633
percDiff(1000, 1500); //=> 50
percDiff(1000, 500); //=> 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculatePercentageDifference(valueA, valueB) {
  const difference = valueB - valueA;
  const percentageDifference = Math.abs((difference / valueA) * 100);
  return percentageDifference;
}

// Example values
const valueA = 50000;
const valueB = 80000;

const percentDiff = calculatePercentageDifference(valueA, valueB);
console.log(percentDiff); // Output: 60
```